# How to change push() method to simple code?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix

I have this code but it's static and I wanna change it dynamically.

```
function addCandidates(){
 if( own == 1 ){
    candidate[0].candidate_ID[0] = 1;
    candidate[0].candidate_ID[1] = 2;
    candidate[0].candidate_ID[2] = 3;
    candidate[0].candidateslength = 3;

    candidate[0].voteCount[0] = 0;
    candidate[0].voteCount[1] = 0;
    candidate[0].voteCount[2] = 0;
 }
}
```

It's static code in UPPAAL toll and I wanna change this above code to solidity code that is:

```
struct Candidate {
        string name;
        uint voteCount; 
}
Candidate[] public candidates; 
function addCanditate(string memory _name) ownerOnly public {
        candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0)); 
}
```

So how can I use 1st UPPAAL code to 2nd solidity code without using push method dynamically?
Anyone have any idea it will be appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what do you want to achieve.  Could you show how `candidates` and `Candidate` are declared, and explain what exactly do you want?

Comment: Hi Mikhail Vladimirov actually i wanna add candidates in contract but I have code in uppaal so i wanna change it dynamically so I cant use push method because uppaal is not supporting this method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you be more clear? Think that most people here doesn't know what uppaal is, we have more familiarity with Ethereum/Solidity.

Comment: Just wanna know that can i use something else without using push method in solidity. I wanna add candidates to Candidate structure in solidity without using any function just wanna follow this code:
function addCandidates(){
 if( own == 1 ){
    candidate[0].candidate_ID[0] = 1;
    candidate[0].candidate_ID[1] = 2;
    candidate[0].candidate_ID[2] = 3;
    candidate[0].candidateslength = 3;

    candidate[0].voteCount[0] = 0;
    candidate[0].voteCount[1] = 0;
    candidate[0].voteCount[2] = 0;
 }
}
@Ismael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use push with an array. You can add a new element modifying its length.

```
Candidate[] public candidates;

function addCandidate(string memory _name) public {
  uint idx = candidates.length;
  candidates.length += 1;
  candidates[idx].name = _name;
}
```

Another option is to use a mapping. You will need to keep the length separately.

```
mapping (uint => Candidate) public candidates;
uint public numCandidates = 0;

function addCandidate(string memory _name) public {
  uint idx = numCandidates;
  numCandidates += 1;
  candidates[idx].name = _name;
}
```

Comment: still it's not working bro. It's giving me this error
browser/Election.sol:66:32: TypeError: Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
        candidates[idx].name = _name;
                               ^---^

Comment: @Abbas It is working with the definition of Candidate in your answer. The errors is that you are using uint instead of string for the name field.

Comment: thanks bro got it. so i got code without push method but actually i wanna write code same like this:
if( own == 1 ){
        candidate[0].candidate_ID[0] = 1;
        candidate[0].candidate_ID[1] = 2;
        candidate[0].candidate_ID[2] = 3;
        candidate[0].candidateslength = 3;

        candidate[0].voteCount[0] = 0;
        candidate[0].voteCount[1] = 0;
        candidate[0].voteCount[2] = 0;
    }
in solidity.

Comment: can you convert this code to solidity code? using same array?

Comment: @Abbas Sorry, I don't know upaal, I don't know what that code does. What's `candidate[0]`? What's `candidate_ID`? If you write it in another language like C or Java perhaps I can help.

Comment: Hey do you have answer for this question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/76824/48694
now I guess you are familiar with my problems so you can solve.